# Material UI Multiple Select | How to use Multiple Select with arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm using material-ui multiple select and I've created an example based on the documentation provided from [Multiple Select](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select).

My example here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-2t2ny?file=/demo.js:926-1004)

In my example, I want to use 2 arrays for multiple select dropdowns, 1 for each. I tried to achieve this by updating the `handleChange` event from:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState(event.target.value);
  };
```

to:

```
const handleChange = event => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

When I test this update, I click on any name from the drop-down and I get this error: `state.indexOf is not a function`

I want to be able to use the `handleChange` event to work for all of the multiple select drop-downs for my example. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Please change the handleChange() :-> const handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event);
    setState(event.target.value);
  };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your codesandbox, you have used only one array as state which should be changed to two

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ first: [], second: [] });
```

For each select we have to give the name

```
<Select
      labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
      id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
      multiple
      value={state.first}
      name="first"
      onChange={handleChange}
      input={<Input />}
      renderValue={selected => selected.join(", ")}
    >
```

this is the working csb link https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-s1g4h?file=/demo.js:1322-1618